# Htaccess and rewriting rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've this in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(panel/index.php)
RewriteRule ^panel/(.*)$    panel/index.php/$1/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to tunnel all links containing `panel/(.*)` to `panel/index.php` for controlling them.

Above rules works except if url is `http://localhost/test/panel/`! that it redirects to :

`http://localhost/test/panel/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php/`

Helps needed.

Comment: Why are you treating `index.php` as a directory? You probably want the rewrite patern to be something like `RewriteRule ^panel/(.*)$    panel/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]` so that `index.php` is actually called.

Comment: @G-Nugget i did it. but the result is the same.

Comment: so it's not supposed to actually run `index.php`?

Comment: @G-Nugget, it's not! it just for checking urls & doing works in php.

Comment: @rev Do you have another .htaccess in `panel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #skip rewrite for  index.php
    RewriteRule ^panel/index.php(.*)$ - [S=1,L]
    RewriteRule ^panel/(.*)$    panel/index.php/$1/ [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: it doesn't work either. root directory is `test`, and `panel` is a sub directoty in it. .htaccess is put at root. with this scenario it doesn't work for me,